# Why col-md-3 is stacking images into a column

Tags: html, css

Im wondering how I can put my images into a horizontal row instead of a column. It worked for the "services" part of the code. Im following this video, that displays all the code on screen.. yet i still cant figure it out. Heres a URL of the video and the code is at 51:00 minutes in  https://youtu.be/99vHH_6F0Ko?t=3064

```css
/*---------Services---------*/
#services {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)),url(images/services.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #efefef !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#services h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #efefef !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#services h1::after {
  content: '';
  background: #efefef;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 20px auto 5px;

}
.services {

  margin-top: 40px;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

#services p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #ccc;

}

.services .col-md-3:hover {
  background: #007bff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
/*------------TEAM MEMBERS----------*/
#team {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  color: #555;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #555 !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h1::after {
  content: '';
  background: #007bff;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 20px auto 5px;

}
.profile-pic {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.profile-pic .img-box {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  }

  .profile-pic .img-box img {
    filter: grayscale(1);
  }

  .profile-pic .img-box img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    cursor: pointer;

  }

 .profile-pic h2 {
   font-size: 22px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 15px;
   color: #007bff !important;
 }

 .profile-pic h3 {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 15px;

 }

 #team .fa {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  color: #007bff !important;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.img-box ul {
  padding: 15px 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   top: 220px;
   opacity: 0;

}

.img-box ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;

}

.img-box:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

.img-box ul, .img-box ul li {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Business Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
   awesome.min.css"

  script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"> 
</script>
</script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- -Services- -->
<section id="services">
<div class="container">
<h1>Our Services</h1>
<div class="row services">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
    </div>
    <h3>Web Development</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
    </div>
    <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
    </div>
    <h3>Digital Marketing</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>
    </div>
    <h3>E-Commerce</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </section>
 <!---Team Members- -->
 <section id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Our Team</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 profile-pic text-center">
        <div class="img-box">
          <img src="images/teampic.png" class="img-fluid">
          <ul>
  <a href="#"><li<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li></a>
  <a href="#"><li<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
  <a href="#"><li<i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
 </ul>
            <div>
              <h2>Elon Musk</h2>
              <h3>Founder/CEO</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 profile-pic text-center">
            <div class="img-box">
              <img src="images/team2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
                <div>
                  <h2>Elon Musk</h2>
                  <h3>Founder/CEO</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>

<body>
```

Comment: You missed to close the `<div class="img-box">` and the first `col-md-3` https://codepen.io/m4n0/pen/YzNRKob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an error in your HTML markup.

You have put your 2nd profile div inside the 1st profile div i.e nested divs.

So it's applying its style on the 2nd profile div as well.

Just remove that div and put it outside 1st profile div. Like below.

```css
#services {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)),url(images/services.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #efefef !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#services h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #efefef !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#services h1::after {
  content: '';
  background: #efefef;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 20px auto 5px;

}
.services {

  margin-top: 40px;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

#services p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #ccc;

}

.services .col-md-3:hover {
  background: #007bff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
/*------------TEAM MEMBERS----------*/
#team {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  color: #555;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #555 !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h1::after {
  content: '';
  background: #007bff;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 20px auto 5px;

}
.profile-pic {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.profile-pic .img-box {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  }

  .profile-pic .img-box img {
    filter: grayscale(1);
  }

  .profile-pic .img-box img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    cursor: pointer;

  }

 .profile-pic h2 {
   font-size: 22px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 15px;
   color: #007bff !important;
 }

 .profile-pic h3 {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 15px;

 }

 #team .fa {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  color: #007bff !important;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.img-box ul {
  padding: 15px 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   top: 220px;
   opacity: 0;

}

.img-box ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;

}

.img-box:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

.img-box ul, .img-box ul li {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<section id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Our Team</h1>
    <div class="row">
    <!-- First profile div 33% width -->
      <div class="col-md-3 profile-pic text-center"> 
        <div class="img-box">
          <img src="images/teampic.png" class="img-fluid">
          <ul>
  <a href="#"><li<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li></a>
  <a href="#"><li<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
  <a href="#"><li<i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
 </ul>
            <div>
              <h2>Elon Musk</h2>
              <h3>Founder/CEO</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
          </div>
          
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Second profile div 33% width -->
<div class="col-md-3 profile-pic text-center"> 
    <div class="img-box">
      <img src="images/team2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      <ul>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
</ul>
        <div>
          <h2>Elon Musk</h2>
          <h3>Founder/CEO</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

[image: screenshot]